# UFT API Test How can I extract and save XLS values from the XML response?

Tags: c#, xml, uft-api

I am new to the UFT API Test, and I need to extract certain values ​​from the XML response to be included in an existing XLS, which will serve as input data for another test.
This is my XML Response:

```
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS3:BuscaSaldosCaptacionOut xmlns:NS3="http://www.portal.com/ws/esb/ConsultaCuentasSaldos">
     <SaldosCaptacion>
        <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
        <Cuenta>0201484326</Cuenta>
        <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
        <SubProductoCuenta>0382</SubProductoCuenta>
        <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
        <IdCuenta>0201484326</IdCuenta>
        <SaldoInicialDia>7062.42</SaldoInicialDia>
        <SaldoPromedio>30596.01</SaldoPromedio>
        <SaldoActual>17062.42</SaldoActual>
        <SaldoDisponible>17062.42</SaldoDisponible>
        <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
     </SaldosCaptacion>
     <SaldosCaptacion>
        <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
        <Cuenta>0201484371</Cuenta>
        <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
        <SubProductoCuenta>0340</SubProductoCuenta>
        <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
        <SaldoInicialDia>6825.11</SaldoInicialDia>
        <SaldoPromedio>8936.26</SaldoPromedio>
        <SaldoActual>6825.11</SaldoActual>
        <SaldoDisponible>6825.11</SaldoDisponible>
        <SaldoRetenido>0.00</SaldoRetenido>
        <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
     </SaldosCaptacion>
     <SaldosCaptacion>
        <NumeroCliente>51844068</NumeroCliente>
        <Cuenta>0201533729</Cuenta>
        <ProductoCuenta>01</ProductoCuenta>
        <SubProductoCuenta>0363</SubProductoCuenta>
        <Divisa>MXP</Divisa>
        <SaldoInicialDia>28316.52</SaldoInicialDia>
        <SaldoPromedio>6230.52</SaldoPromedio>
        <SaldoActual>7374.52</SaldoActual>
        <SaldoDisponible>7374.52</SaldoDisponible>
        <SaldoRetenido>942.00</SaldoRetenido>
        <EstatusCuenta>A</EstatusCuenta>
     </SaldosCaptacion>
  </NS3:BuscaSaldosCaptacionOut>
```

I need save "Cuenta" and "SaldoActual" values. (Everybody), and completely ignore how to parameterize them.
The "Write to file" option does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.  If it doesn't work then the namespace needs to be changed in code.  I can't tell the correct namespace because you did post the beginning of the xml file.  I'm using xml linq which is a Net Library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants("SaldosCaptacion").Select(x => new {
                Cuenta = (string)x.Element("Cuenta"),
                SaldoActual = (decimal)x.Element("SaldoActual")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```